# TestNG&appium: how to run 2 or more test cases continuously if i use @BeforeMethod、@AfterMethod and DependsOnMethods

Tags: testng, appium

```
@BeforeMethod
    public void startUp() throws MalformedURLException{
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        System.out.println("start appium service");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", xxxxx/xxx.app");
        driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }


    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        System.out.println("test1");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods={"test1"})
    public void test2()
    {
        System.out.println("test2");
    }

    @Test
    public void test3()
    {
        System.out.println("test3");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() throws Exception 
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Expected results:

1. "start appium service"----
2. test1----
3. test2----
4. "start appium service"----
5. test3----

I just want start appium serviceand excute test1 and test2 continuously.Then restart appium service, excute test3 seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Use `resetApp()` method before Test3. `driver.resetApp()`